# About conservative extensions of first order theories?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let $T_1$ be an effectively axiomatized first order theory whose language have only finitely many primitive symbols.

Now let $L^{T_1}$ be the set of all formulas of the language of $T_1$.

Let $L^{T_1}_S$ be the set of all *sentences* of the language of $T_1$

Where a [sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(mathematical_logic)) is a well formed formula with no free variables.

Now Let $F$ be a definable meta-theoretic syntactical injection from $L^{T_1}_S$ to $L^{T_2}_S$, like for example in saying that $F$ is the bounding of all quantifiers in $\phi$ by the constant symbol $V$ by relation $\in$ for every $\phi$ in $L^{T_1}_S$, Formally:

$F:L^{T_1}_S \to L^{T_2}_S, F(\phi) = \phi^V$,

Clearly $F$ is injective.

Now if we have: $\forall \phi \ \epsilon \  L^{T_1}_S [(T_1 \vdash \phi) \implies (T_2 \vdash F(\phi))]$

Where "$\vdash$" is syntactical provability.

Then we'd say that $T_2$ extends $T_1$ through $F$.

If we have:
$\forall \phi \ \epsilon \  L^{T_1}_S [(T_1 \vdash \phi) \iff (T_2 \vdash F(\phi))]$

We say that $T_2$ *conservatively* extends $T_1$ through $F$.

> Question1: Is the following implication true?
>
> If there exists a function $F$ such that $T_2$ conservatively extends $T_1$ through $F$; then for every function $G$ such that $T_2$ extends $T_1$ through $G$, we have $T_2$ conservatively extends $T_1$ through $G$.

Comment: What does it mean to "*bind a quantifier* by some constant symbol"?

Comment: What does "completely bounded formula in the usual sense" mean when we're not talking about languages such as $\{\in\}$ or the language of arithmetic ?

Comment: @Max, it means there is no free variables, all variables are bound by quantifiers in the sentence.

Comment: Ah ok sorry I was mistaking the name with something else

Comment: @Max, thanks for showing me that my presentation was confusing, I've edited it.